# SQL different null values in different rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, conceptual

I have a quick question regarding writing a SQL query to obtain a complete entry from two or more entries where the data is missing in different columns.

This is the example, suppose I have this table:

```
Client Id | Name | Email

1234      | John   | (null)
1244      | (null) | john@example.com
```

Would it be possible to write a query that would return the following?

```
Client Id | Name | Email

1234      | John | john@example.com
```

I am finding this particularly hard because these are 2 entires in the same table.

I apologize if this is trivial, I am still studying SQL and learning, but I wasn't able to come up with a solution for this and I although I've tried looking online I couldn't phrase the question in the proper way, I suppose and I couldn't really find the answer I was after.

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How do you know these two rows belong together and should be merged?

Comment: And, furthermore, why would `Client ID` `1234` be chosen over `1244`?

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, but actually no.

It is possible to write a query that works with your example data.
But just under the assumption that the first part of the mail is always equal to the name.

```sql
SELECT clients.id,clients.name,bclients.email FROM clients
JOIN clients bclients ON upper(clients.name) = upper(substring(bclients.email from 0 for position('@' in bclients.email)));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=10bfd018497f3dad3c7063027e125b08)

**Explanation:**
We join the table onto itself, to get the information into one row.
For this we first search for the **position** of the '@' in the *email*, get the **substring** from the start (0) of the string for the amount of characters until we hit the @ (result of *positon*).
To avoid case-problems the name and *substring* are cast to uppercase for comparsion.
*(lowercase would work the same)*

### The design is flawed

How can a client have multiple ids and different kind of information about the same user at the same time?
I think you want to split the table between clients and users, so that a user can have multiple clients.
I recommend that you read information about **database normalization** as this provides you with necessary knowledge for successfull database design.